# Which libraries are used by the make process?

Tags: makefile

My build is failing to link, probably because it's attempting to link against the wrong version of libaries (namely, libssl). The makefile's LIBS directive specifies -lssl, which isn't explicit enough: I have many of these on my system (various system SDKs + newly downloaded version).

My general question is, is there a verbosity option for having make print the explicit paths of the libs used for linking?

Gil.

Answer (score 0):

To see the link step in detail you would usually pass a "verbose" option to the compiler or linker. What system are you using? If gcc, add `-v` to the compile command. This will produce output like

```
$ gcc -v hello.c
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
 /usr/libexec/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/cc1 -quiet -v hello.c -quiet -dumpbase hello.c -mtune=generic -auxbase hello -version -o /tmp/ccAtBXVy.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../i386-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50) (i386-redhat-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50).
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=81 --param ggc-min-heapsize=95810
Compiler executable checksum: d8d95095eb3c93dae4bed2137d559f95
 as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccDL1N2O.o /tmp/ccAtBXVy.s
GNU assembler version 2.17.50.0.6-14.el5 (i386-redhat-linux) using BFD version 2.17.50.0.6-14.el5 20061020
 /usr/libexec/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../.. /tmp/ccDL1N2O.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crtn.o
```

Where the last line is the link command in all its glory. The `-L` options specify the directories where the libs given by `-l` are searched, in order.

Comment: Your linker command line specifies -lgcc_s, however the output you placed here does not show the full path to that library. That is exactly what I'm missing.

Comment: In my case, I indeed see many -L options, and the library could be in any one of them. I just want to know against which of them the linker tried to link.

Comment: The one found first by looking in the `-L` directories, in sequence.

Comment: You mean, I have to look in each of the dozen directories, one by one, until I find the library used? Absolutely no linker verbosity of the actual file used?

Comment: I suggest you read your linkers manual page to see if there's an option for that. On the other hand, you might try tracing the open() system calls with `strace` to see which files are read.